# Can one make a bootable device with several distros of Linux?

Tags: linux, distributions, live-usb, bios, bootable

I think this question explains itself. But here are some more details anyway:

Many Linux distributions have "live USB's" which one can use to try and install that distro. However, that pen must often be formatted, and even afterwords, it can only have the purpose to install that one distribuition.

Why can't one have a directory for each distro and have BIOS boot from that? (maybe including some file leading to other the files from which to boot, but not having them all laying in the top directory of that drive) How? Which distribuitions support that? Can you make such a file for BIOS to detect and find the bootable files for several distros? (then one should choose from which one to boot from, like when a computer has several operating systems)

Comment: You could do this fairly easily—just add multiple partitions, with a different root= and initramfs= for each in the grub config.

Comment: @derobert, in what way is that easy? I'm a beginner. Can you put that in an answer?

Comment: Searching, it appears someone has already done this work: http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/

Comment: @derobert that gives several headache and I would not recommend it for newbies (I couldn't make it work, figures).

Comment: @Braiam The grub approach, or MultiCD?

Comment: MultiCD, the grub *"should"* work nevertheless but it requires a amount of \*effort\*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to roll your own version of this concept with Grub.  However there are also tools that can make the process much easier.

[PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) lists several tools.  Of those I have had good luck with [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), which is Windows based, and [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/) which is Linux-based.  The MultiSystem project website is in French, but PenDriveLinux has good instructions.

I've created multi-distro USB keys with both of these with good results.

Comment: Thanks, +1, I'll try those options and mark this as answered as soon as I get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

**Ventoy works for me** for this exact purpose (multiple Linux distros), and was very easy to set up.
https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

**Easy2Boot is also designed to do this, but I could not get it to work myself**.
(ISO files were not visible in its menu, even if I processed them through the ISO conversion tool E2B recommends using.  Linking it here as well though, since it seems to work for some people.)
https://easy2boot.xyz/

Extra note that might be obvious to some but wasn't obvious to me:  When putting .iso files onto a Ventoy drive (it really is just copy and paste!), in addition to Linux distro ISOs you *could also add ISOs with system tools (like partition managers, etc.)*.  Think recovery disc, or swiss army knife util disc.  One boot drive for everything!