# USB Boot Flash Drive consolidation

Tags: boot, live-usb

I would like to consolidate a dozen small 2-4 GB sticks that were created to install Operating Systems (Ubuntu / Windows), as well as apps such as Clonezilla.  The .iso files for each stick is available.

It would be nice to "stack" the .iso files on a large bootable USB stick, that is outfitted with a boot mechanism that will allow the user to choose that .iso file (vs burning the .iso file to the stick).  A bonus feature would be the ability to automatically detect newly added .iso files or removed .iso files and update the menu selection appropriately.

To clarify a constraint: I seek to avoid "burning" the .iso file to a partition of the USB stick.

What is the general class of applications that provides said capability to consolidate?

"All things being even": the preference is for a UNIX (Ubuntu) solutions to burn the USB stick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one make a bootable device with several distros of Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93205/can-one-make-a-bootable-device-with-several-distros-of-linux)

Comment: @K7AAY Good observation,  however, my questions is not confined to LINUX distros: I would like to be able to select an .iso to install Windows.  Perhaps it makes no difference whether the .iso is NIX or other OS?

Comment: How 'bout them Gators!  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483317/make-multiboot-usb-containing-windows-and-linux-iso-using-a-linux-pc shows three leading contenders: Multibootusb, Multisystem, and Yumi.

Comment: I run Yumi under WINE to do this. It works well.

Comment: you can use GRUB for this

Comment: @jsotola  Please consider providing an example as an `answer`.

Comment: I use USB pendrives as temporary drives: I store my iso files on my main computer's HDD and keep them up to date. When I want to boot into a live system, I flash from its iso file to a pendrive and use it. (The iso files are updated to new versions quite often, so it is a lot of work to keep a multiboot pendrive up to date.)

Answer (score 1):

Easy2Boot allows you to just add or delete ISO files and can boot 99% of all linux ISOs that way (Legacy boot).
But defragging the drive under Linux can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ventoy works for me for this exact purpose (multiple Linux distros), and was very easy to set up.
https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

I also tried Easy2Boot but could not get it to work, even after using the ISO conversion tool recommended.

I tried Easy2Boot before Ventoy because Easy2Boot comes with some default tools (like a partition manager, if I recall correctly) and I liked the idea of having those, but having extra tools can be easily accomplished with Ventoy by just, in addition to putting Linux distro .iso files on it, also putting an extra tools .iso file (or more than one) on it.

Comment: Were you able to install Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows installation files on the same USB with Ventoy?

Comment: Installing an installation file onto a Ventoy drive just means copying the ISO to the drive (and actually the root of the drive, not even any special folder).  I did put a Windows installation file and installation files for many Linux distributions (though not Ubuntu) on the drive, yes.  I have not tried to boot those OSs though.  So far I've launched Mint and Fedora from it, and they boot worked without a hitch.